# Files with no .sh extension not considered for autocompletion in zsh

Tags: shell-script, zsh, autocomplete

I have noticed that unless I add an `.sh` extension to my shell scripts, Zsh does not suggest them for autocompletion **for execution** despite having them in my `PATH`. I have the same problem if I `cd` into the directory and start typing the filename.

When I say for execution I mean typing the file directly on the prompt, i.e.:

```
$ my_shell_script
```

Are there any options in Zsh that control which file extensions are considered for this type of autocompletion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have your shell scripts start with the appropriate shebang (`#!`) and with the execution permission bits on. `zsh` will then recognize them as proper executable files.

(With some configurations, you might have to refresh `zsh` paths cache. Restarting it with `exec zsh` is one way to do it.)

Comment: `rehash` is a Zsh builtin which does exactly that.